# Outsourcing code development

Tags: discussion

I think this is not the right place to ask for an estimation of the time required for the development of a specific website. But I guess techniques for making estimation are on topic.

And what about asking for suggestion about team management and outsourcing? Would it fit here? Or other section like startup would be better?

I actually see IT not only as forever programming, but also future technical managers which have to deal with estimations and team management.

Comment: consider checking recent questions tagged [tag:estimation] and [tag:outsourcing] to see what kind works well and what is less welcome

Comment: thanks for the help. +1

Comment: I would also check over at [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) but be sure to read their help center to see what is on and off topic. You may find that your question really is two questions, one about the team management aspect and one about the time estimation. They may be on-topic at different SE sites.